# read line till certain point and insert it into jList in java

Tags: java, netbeans, jlist, readfile

hey I want to read the name of each array from a text file and add it to a jList in netbeans for example for:

```
number[1,2,3]
alphabet[a,b,c]
```

i will get "number" and "alphabet" inserted into jList

UPDATE:
I tried using a seperate method to get the values into the jlist buut it still woudnt work

method to get name and put in array

```
public String getLine(int whatLine) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("./"+jList1.getSelectedValue());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
    for(int i = 0; i < whatLine; ++i)
      br.readLine();
     String lineIWant = br.readLine();
    return lineIWant;
}
public String[] getArrayName() throws IOException{
   String Name;
   String NameArray[] =new String[999];
   for(int i = 0; i < 9999; ++i){
       Name=getLine(i);
       NameArray[i]  = Name.split("\\[")[0];
   }
   return NameArray;
}
```

putting it into jlist

```
    javax.swing.JList<String> jList2 = new javax.swing.JList<>();

jList2.setModel(new DefaultListModel(){
    String[] name=getArrayName();
    public int getSize() { return name.length; }
    public String getElementAt(int i) { return name[i]; }

});

jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList2);
```

currently its giving me a throw IOException error at String[] name=getArrayName(); but I cant do that because it is not a method

Comment: You should try to use a regular expression for this. Match all word characters til the first `[`, extract the matched sequence with a matching group and add the result to your list. Doesn't look like you have already tried a lot to solve your problem.

Comment: i tried using readears but i can get it to read to specific point in each line

Comment: Read the whole line and use a regex to extract the name of the array.

Comment: @Wasi Ul Hassan you need to show what you have tried so far.  Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and post an [mcve]